# Stop switching content orientation in double-sided article

Tags: appendices, double-sided, landscape, article

Is it possible to stop the switching content orientation of appendices when using a double-sided article? I want to keep the same fixed orientation of all figures, but every time an appendix is inserted, it causes the following figures in landscape mode to change orientation.

I were thinking of just changing to one-sided page-layout only for appendices, but couldn't determine if it was possible/the best solution. I want them to be fixed in order to ease the readability :)

Please ask for further information if necessary.

Comment: Wild guess: read 2.1 Package options of the documentation of the rotating package.

Comment: Simple as that: Adding 'figureright' og 'figureleft' to the rotating-package solved the problem. Thanks again @UlrikeFischer!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Write up an essay, m'kay... :)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you want to write an answer?

Answer (score 1):

As Ulrike Fischer mentioned in the comments your error is based on the usage of the `rotating` package. You can read in section 2.1 of its documentation:

> If the ‘twoside’ option has been given to the main document class
>   (either explicitly, or implicitly as in the default for book class),
>   the package will rotate sideways figures according to the page number
>   (this requires at least two passes through LATEX). If you want the
>   ‘twoside’ option, but want the figures always in one direction, use
>   the ‘figuresright’ or ‘figuresleft’ options to the package.

So the easiest version is to decide in favor of one orientation and pass it as stated above as package option.